# why this code is declared like this by using 't'

Tags: java.util.scanner

why this code is reading the inputs using the variable t?   three variable scanning with another variable

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int t=0;
int a=0;
int b=0;
int n=0;
t=in.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
    a = in.nextInt();
    b = in.nextInt();    
    n = in.nextInt(); 
}
```

Comment: Your code is not complete, please fix your question. And please, use [markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Comment: Format your code properly and elaborate on what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Did you try thinking about it, or running it? It seems fairly clear.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of this code:-

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=0;
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    int n=0;
    t=in.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        a = in.nextInt();
        b = in.nextInt();    
        n = in.nextInt(); 
}
```

Lets understand this with an example

say you enter t =3;so for loop will run three times.

At very first iteration when i=0
 a,b,n will get value using command line say a=1,b=2,n=9

At the second iteration again you need to assign values to a,b,n and the old values get overrides. say u assign a=3, b=0,n=5

At the last iteration again values assigned and loop exits and the iteration values will persist in a,b and n.

In the *for loop* a = in.nextInt() will led you to command line and you need to enter one integer value for a, similarly for b and n.so in this you enter values for all(a,b,n) of them **t** times.